# SPF record for hostname of postfix instead for every sending domain

Tags: domain, spf, email-server

I am having a server reachable via `server.com` that has a postfix mailserver running with the hostname `gaia.server.com`.
Because reverse DNS is only needed for mail purpose (afaik) I changed the reverse DNS entry of my server ip `1.2.3.4` to `gaia.server.com`, which works perfectly fine.

I inserted this in a TXT entry in my domains DNS server:
v=spf1 mx ip4:1.2.3.4 -all

This record was created by [this tool](http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/).

Now I want to send emails from `email1@server.com` or `email2@different-domain.com`, which is an address of a different domain pointing to the same ip address as `server.com`.

Now I used http://www.brandonchecketts.com/emailtest.php for testing this configuration.
It gives me `gaia.server.com` as the `Helo Address` and `email1@server.com` as the `From Address`. But then it looks up the SPF record for the `From Address` domain `server.com`.

Please, correct me if I am wrong, but I thought it would look up the mail server ip, reverses it to a hostname and then checks the SPF of that hostname.
Or am I wrong there and the reverse checking is just another part in the spam checking?

My question is: How and what do I need to configure to make the SPF record work for all domains sending by this server.
I would prefer not to put a hardcoded ip address in each an every domain, if possible.
What would be best practice for such a case?

Thanks for reading and your help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I used http://www.brandonchecketts.com/emailtest.php for testing this configuration. It gives me gaia.server.com as the Helo Address and email1@server.com as the From Address. But then it looks up the SPF record for the From Address domain server.com.

The default specification of SPF is check the **sender** domain part. Whenever some server sent you a email with header envelope `MAIL_FROM: <forged_address@gmail.com>`, the SPF will take the domain of sender (i.e. gmail.com) and **check the SPF published by gmail.com**. For more info, check the FAQ from http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/What_it_does

> Please, correct me if I am wrong, but I thought it would look up the mail server ip, reverses it to a hostname and then checks the SPF of that hostname. Or am I wrong there and the reverse checking is just another part in the spam checking?

The partial process you described above is another spam measurement from mail server. It's called **rDNS test**. The whole process is given below

1. The receiving server determines the IP of the sender. This could be obtained directly from the connection or extracted from the email Received headers.
2. Through an RDNS query the host name for this IP is retreived.
3. Next the host name is fed to a forward DNS query, obtaining the IP from the A record.
4. The test is successful if the sender IP matches the one returned by the forward DNS query.

For additional information, take a look on this article [Anti-Spam Reverse DNS Testing](http://www.exchangeinbox.com/article.aspx?i=165).

> My question is: How and what do I need to configure to make the SPF record work for all domains sending by this server. I would prefer not to put a hardcoded ip address in each an every domain, if possible. What would be best practice for such a case?

SPF test was performed per domain basis. If your server want sent email from a.example.com, b.example.com, c.example.com, then each domain of them must have its own SPF record.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But regarding the rDNS test. What does the term `sender` stand for? The sending server or as the SPF check the sending domain?

Comment: @func0der IP address of sending server

Answer (score 5):

SPF records are per-domain, not per-server.  They're essentially a list of IPs that are specifically allowed to send mail on behalf of a particular domain.

Your SPF record for `server.com` handles emails with from addresses of `@server.com`.  If you want to apply SPF to emails with addresses of `@different-domain.com`, then you need to add an SPF record to `different-domain.com`'s DNS.

If you want to use the SPF record for `server.com` on `different-domain.com` without hardcoding the IPs, use either the [include](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#include) or [redirect](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#redirect) keywords for `different-domain.com`'s TXT record:

```
different-domain.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 include=server.com -all"
```

or

```
different-domain.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 redirect=server.com"
```

Comment: Thanks :) I'm sorry, but I need to mark masegaleohs answer as THE answer, because it is more detailed and corrects my incorrect statements. Nevertheless: Up vote ;)